# Using navigation_stack with a fixed map and no amcl

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have robot that uses the ekf node in the robot_localization package and a static map that I can load onto the map_server and I used a static tf publisher to publish frame info from odom to map. I would be able to provide the robot with its initial position (assuming the robot will always start from a fixed point on the map), so I don't need amcl. The problem is that when I send a goal pose to the robot, the path created will penetrate the obstacle areas in that map as shown the screenshot.

[image: image description]

Does anybody have any idea how to use a static map with ekf only (no amcl)?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352080/using-navigation_stack-with-a-fixed-map-and-no-amcl/) by [zoidberg2010eaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/40045/zoidberg2010eaf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL doesn't do any path planning so that isn't related to your issue.
Move_base calls path planners that use costmaps to do the planning so make sure your costmaps are set up properly which is covered in the navigation stack tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2020-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zoidberg2010eaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/40045/zoidberg2010eaf/) on 2020-05-14**:
Yes my problem with the global costmap configuration not with the localization. Thank you.